# Envio de anexo direto para o e-mail

Tags: php, upload

Eu uso um formulário bem simples de envio de dados para e-mail, eu incluí um botão de upload... Como faria uma programação simples pra que esse arquivo seja enviado no e-mail como anexo?

```
<div class="contato">
<div class="container">
    <h2>Inscreva-se já!</h2>
    <form action="email-2.php" method="post">

        <input type="text" name="nome" size="" placeholder="Nome Completo"><br>

        <input type="text" name="endereco" size="" placeholder="Endereço"><br>

        <input type="text" name="cpf" size="" placeholder="CPF"><br>

        <input type="text" name="rg" size="" placeholder="RG"><br>

        <input type="text" name="fone" size="" placeholder="Telefone"><br>

        <input type="text" name="email" size="" placeholder="E-mail"><br>

        <input type="file" />

        <textarea name="mensagem" cols="65" rows="8" placeholder="Escreva aqui sua mensagem"></textarea><br>
        <div class="botao-contato">
            <input class="botao" type="submit" value="Enviar"><br> 
        </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

```
<?php
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$endereco = $_POST['endereco'];
$cpf = $_POST['cpf'];
$rg = $_POST['rg'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$fone = $_POST['fone'];
$msg = $_POST['mensagem'];

$destino = "destino@gmail.com";
$assunto = "Cadastro Via Site";


$headers = "From: ". $nome;
$headers .= "\r\n" . 'Cc: destino2@gmail.com' . "\r\n";

$corpoemail = 'Contato Via site

           Nome: '   .$nome.' 
           Endereço: '   .$endereco.' 
           CPF: '   .$cpf.'
           RG: '   .$rg.'
           Email: '   .$email.'
           Fone: ' .$fone.' 
           Mensagem: '.$msg.' ';




if(mail($destino, $assunto, $corpoemail, $headers)){


   echo "<script>alert('Cadastro enviado com 
sucesso!');document.location='index.php';</script>";

} else{

  echo "<script>alert('Erro ao enviar, tente diretamente pelo 
destino@gmail.com');</script>";  

}

?>
```

Comment: Use a biblioteca php mailer: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer Código de exemplo de anexo usando AddAttachment https://code.google.com/archive/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/wikis/AdvancedMail.wiki